# Finding what string comes last alphabetically out of three strings

Tags: java

```
String wordOne = "Hello";
String wordTwo = "Bye";
String wordThree = "What";
```

Assuming that these are strings that the user has entered. While not being case-sensitive, how would I go about finding which word/string comes last alphabetically using only `if`-statements? I have started by using the `.toUpperCase` to try and use ASCII values but I am lost. Also, the user would be able to enter words that are the same. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried comparing the two first characters' ASCII values in `wordOne` and `wordTwo` to see which one comes first. But i can't seem to get any farther than that

Comment: so us your code, edit your question and append the code that you are having trouble with and why

Answer (score -1):

Use the compareToIgnoreCase() function,

```
   int result= wordOne.compareToIgnoreCase(wordTwo);
   if(result < 0){
        //wordOne precedes wordTwo alphabetically
   }
   else if(result > 0){
         //wordOne is after wordTwo alphabetically
   }
   else{
         //they are the same
   }
```

Documentation here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: As the OP has not shown any code, I would say that it is impossible to know what the OP is having trouble with. As a rule of thumb it is not a good idea to post answers to questions that are not at all clear and show no attempt to solve themselves or show any research

Comment: Since OP provided 3 lines of code and a question pertaining to that code that's more than enough to answer the question.

Comment: Really? How does your answer address the case sensitivity issue and the 3 Strings issue ?  And why do you post a link to Java6 Javadocs?

Comment: Good catch, fixed both with Java 8 documentation.